# Как передать интент в уже запущенный сервис?

Tags: java

Нашел код запуска сервиса и отправки значения в него:

```
startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class).putExtra("time", 7));
```

Можно ли отправить интент в уже запущенный сервис?

Answer (score 1):

Собственно так и нужно передавать в уже запущенный сервис.

Если он ещё не запущен - будет `onCreate` вызван и `onStartCommand`. Если уже запущен - только `onStartCommand`.